# Can't fetch data from iCloud using CloudKit's CKQueryOperation

Tags: ios, swift

I have implemented a CloudKit fetching function.
However I have some problem here. When I use the code below

```
    let cloudContainer = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
    let publicDatabase = cloudContainer.publicCloudDatabase
    let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Restaurant", predicate: predicate)

    publicDatabase.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil, completionHandler: {
        results, error in
        if error == nil {
            print("Completed the download of Restauran data")
            self.restaurants = results! as [CKRecord]
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
        } else {
            print(error)
        }
    })
```

I can successfully fetch the data. However, once I change the code like

```
    restaurants = []
    let cloudContainer = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
    let publicDatabase = cloudContainer.publicCloudDatabase

    let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Restaurant", predicate: predicate)

    let queryOperation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
    queryOperation.desiredKeys = ["name", "image"]
    queryOperation.queuePriority = .VeryHigh
    queryOperation.resultsLimit = 50

    queryOperation.recordFetchedBlock = { (record:CKRecord!) -> Void in
        if let restaurantRecord = record {
            self.restaurants.append(restaurantRecord)
        }
    }

    queryOperation.queryCompletionBlock = { [unowned self] (cursor, error) in
        if (error != nil) {
            print("Failed to get data from iCloud - \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            print("Successfully retrieve the data form iCloud")
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
        }
    }

    publicDatabase.addOperation(queryOperation)
```

using CKQueryOperation, I will fail to fetch the data. I wonder where the problem is.

**update on 10.8**

I've been trying lots of way to figure this out. I find that the app don't even enter the `recordFetchedBlock` and `queryCompletionBlock`. I don't know why this happens.

Comment: I don't know, but I wanted to let you know that I've had instances where the two callback functions don't get called.  In my case, it was when I didn't have internet.  No error or callback was performed.  Though generally it worked for me.  But because of this problem, I ended up using performQuery as much as possible because I couldn't trust addOperation.  I'm new to iCloud.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, today I fixed bugs for your requested code. It's now working... Please ask me if you need further assistance. Thanks.

```
restaurants = []
let cloudContainer = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
let publicDatabase = cloudContainer.publicCloudDatabase

let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Restaurant", predicate: predicate)

let queryOperation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
queryOperation.desiredKeys = ["name", "image"]
queryOperation.queuePriority = .VeryHigh
queryOperation.resultsLimit = 50

queryOperation.recordFetchedBlock = { (record:CKRecord!) -> Void in

    self.restaurants.append(record)
}

queryOperation.queryCompletionBlock = { (cursor: CKQueryCursor?, error: NSError?) in
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    if (error != nil) {
        print("Failed to get data from iCloud - \(error!.localizedDescription)")
    } else {
        print("Successfully retrieve the data form iCloud")
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You haven't used variable "publicDatabase" to perform query.